# Use Dreamweaver regex to add file extension

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have a project where I've exported an html file to be sanitized in preparation for a language translation. The problem is that the internal links do not have the ".html" extension. I've solved the problem of erasing the long file paths, but appending the remaining file is the problem.

The raw file path is:

href="https://oldsite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/actualpage

I use this regex to find all instances of 'https://oldsite.com" and subfolders, adapting it to how many subfolders I have:
(https://oldsite.com)+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9]\w+/[a-zA-Z0-9]\w+/[a-zA-Z0-9]\w+/[a-zA-Z0-9]\w+

Leaving me with "href="actualpage"

The ideal result should be:
href="actualpage.html"

I've been researching this for hours and can't figure out how to append ".html" to the page.

I'm even open to an application or script that can automate this process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and some tutorials, I found a regex that did the trick. After shortening the file paths to one level, I used the following:

**In Dreamweaver:**

**Find**:

```
href="(.*)" title=
```

**Replace:**

```
href="$1.html" title=
```

I performed a massive Find/Replace and was able to fix 1500 files in minutes. Regex is my jam!

I hope this helps other regex noobs like myself.